# Can master.dbo.sysprocesses.login_time have the same values?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, session, unique

is it theoretically possible that two users will login at the same time to the MS SQL server,
so they will have absolutely same values in [master.dbo.sysprocesses.login_time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only a datetime column (not even a datetime2), so it only has ~300 distinct values possible each second. I think you could easily create multiple connections during a period where it stays the same. I'll try to produce a demo, but because it's due to connection start times, it won't be something I can write in just SQL.